# Hibernate returns a proxy for an object set to EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, javassist

We are working with a set of webservices we develop.

One of the services retrieves information from some tables using JPA mappings. Hibernate returns an object and it works as expected.

Other service retrieves a very similar object and it is returning a proxy instead of a read object. The fetch is set to EAGER so I really don't get why is this happening. We tried several ways to convert the proxy to real data (which I understand it is unnecessary as it is set to EAGER) but the proxy does not get converted.

We are working with hibernate 3.5.4-final in case it matters.

I really don't know where to start with, any hint?

```
@Entity
public class Foo1
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Foo2> list = new ArrayList<Foo2>();
}

@Entity
public class Foo2
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Foo3 obj;
}
```

To retrieve the data we call:

```
entityManager.find(Foo1.class, id);
```

One thought I had is that maybe Hibernate is having an internal exception managed and that's why I get a proxy instead of the real object?

**EDIT**
This is the configuration of Hibernate related with the issue:

```
<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="0"/>
<property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16"/>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="16"/>
```

Comment: Can you post that entity class and how you are getting the entity.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu: done, sorry. I should have added it initially.

Comment: Both `Foo2` and `Foo3` are marked as EAGER. I think you are seeing a proxy for `List<Foo2> list`. Can you enable `show_sql` and check whether the queries are getting fired to fetch the EAGER relationships or not?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu: sorry again, it is the obj property of Foo2 the one being proxied. Anyway your suggestion is a very good point. We are going to try it as it is applicable as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the issue calling `entityManager.unProxy` but it still feels wrong as it should be already unProxied as the mapping is set to EAGER.

Comment: ideally it should.load the EAGER collection. Did you get achance to check whether the queries are getting fired to fetch the EAGER relationships or not?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu: the queries are not getting fired in this case.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu: of course this is a simplified example, the real entity (Foo3) has a complex dependency tree. I'm unsure if this can has implications or not.